# Transformer leakage reactance

Tags: electromagnetism

In practical transformers there is always a leakage reactance. If it is possible to construct such a transformer (ideally thinking) having zero leakage reactance will the transformer action work? or not.

Edited: Probably my approach was wrong for that question I actually wants to ask. Now I'm trying to say it clearly. If it is possible to construct the transformer in such a way so that no flux is coming out from the iron core. Means no flux is cutting either primary or secondary. Will the transformer action work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes why wouldn't it? It's just that the coefficient of coupling of the the transformer will be different. As you ask, in the ideal case, all the flux lines generated by the primary winding cut the secondary winding, and all the secondary ones should cut the primary, hence a maximum transfer of energy between the two.

Now in the real case, the leakage flux is non-zero, meaning there are lines of flux generated by one winding that do not link with the other winding. Consequently such lines will not be able to induce a voltage, or in other words there is just less voltage applied on the primary (and the secondary/primary voltages are not directly proportional anymore).
Which boils down to the final expression of voltages also including the impedance of the windings: 
$$\begin{align} 
V_{primary} &= E_1 + I_1(jX_1+R_1) \\
V_{secondary} &= E_2 - I_2(jX_2+R_2) 
\end{align}
$$
With $R_{1,2}$ the resistances of windings, $E_{1,2}$ induced EMFs and $jX_{1,2}$ the reactive resistances.

Comment: But actually my question is about your that line "flux lines generated by the primary winding cut the secondary winding, and all the secondary ones should cut the primary" . It is transformer not motor. Then how can you use "cut the secondary or cut the primary"?  please answer me . This is the main problem. Probably my approach was not correct.

Comment: @SaprativSaha You may be mixing words, because I don't know why you're talking "motor" for? Anyway I explain: Primary/secondary windings are coils, once you pass current through, a magnetic field is induced. The magnetic field created by the primary is mostly confined to and increased by the core, which transmits it to the secondary coil. Any change in current in the primary induces a current in the secondary. And this means by applying Faraday's law, voltages are induced from the rate of change of the magnetic flux $$\Delta \Phi/\Delta t$$.

Comment: "cut the primary..." was another way of saying the flux of magnetic field felt by the coils. Further links that will help you: Voltech: http://www.voltech.com/Articles/104-105%20Leakage%20Inductance/104-105.pdf and Boundless:https://www.boundless.com/physics/induction-ac-circuits-and-electrical-technologies/magnetic-flux-induction-and-faraday-s-law/transformers/